# error in rxdb:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')?

Tags: indexeddb, rxdb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58i4g.jpg)

```
rx-schema-helper.ts:104 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
    at getPrimaryFieldOfPrimaryKey (rx-schema-helper.ts:104:63)
    at fillWithDefaultSettings (rx-schema-helper.ts:163:33)
    at createRxSchema (rx-schema.ts:153:25)
    at rx-database.ts:280:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RxDatabaseBase2.addCollections (rx-database.ts:276:44)
    at index.ts:24:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at creatDataBase (index.ts:22:29)
```

rxSchema:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNEUG.jpg)

why?

use rxdb to undate the data into indexeddb when i change the local data.
or change the properties.

Comment: by use addRxPlugin(RxDBMigrationPlugin);

Comment: `myDatabase.addCollections({ schema, }); `   this ok. but when i use the plugin 'RxDBMigrationPlugin', `myDatabase.addCollections({messages: {schema,migrationStrategies: {2: function (oldDoc: any) {oldDoc.time = new Date(oldDoc.time).getTime(); return oldDoc;},}},})` . it happend